# why error message is showing when unserialize a serialized string from database?

Tags: php

Well, I have following array and variables and it's output is bellow :

```
`print_r($menu_ex_qnt);`

Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)


print_r($menu_extra_item_name);

Array
(
    [0] => 238
    [1] => 239
)

$final_ex = array_combine($menu_ex_name, $menu_ex_qnt);        
print_r($final_ex);

Array
(
    [238] => 1
    [239] => 2
)

echo $final_ex = serialize($final_ex);

a:2:{i:238;s:1:"1";i:239;s:1:"2";}
```

Now, I am inserting this `$final_ex` variable to database.

But when I get this variable from database and try to `unserialize` it then it's showing me following error message :

```
echo unserialize($p_ext_items);
Note : This $p_ext_items contain the serialize string e.g: a:2:{i:238;s:1:"3";i:239;s:1:"1";}

Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 11 of 54 bytes .......
```

why ?

**What I actually want**

There are 2 variables `$menu_ex_qnt` and `$menu_extra_item_name`. I want to save these 2 variables `value` **not** `key` to the database. So that, in final variable there will be `key` and `value` pair.

For e.g:

```
238 => 1
239 => 2
```

Comment: But we don't see value of `$p_ext_items`

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: There is a lot of code / information missing between the `serialize` and `unserialize` calls...

Comment: Are you __sure__ that `$p_ext_items` contains what you expect?

Comment: @u_mulder yes, Im sure

Comment: OH !!!! I used $p_ext_items = htmlspecialchars($result['p_ext_items']); That's why I got error message. I fixed it now. Thanks @Anant

Comment: sure why not ! You know I'm getting this variable data from database that's why I used `htmlspecialchars`. So If i removed it, then is there any security issues ?

Comment: @shibbirahmed No security issue . till it will id's . if it have text then something like those needed `(htmlentities and htmlspecialchars)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said that `$p_ext_items` contains the serialize string which is :- `a:2:{i:238;s:1:"1";i:239;s:1:"2";}`

and you did:-

```
$p_ext_items = htmlspecialchars($result['p_ext_items']);
echo unserialize($p_ext_items);
```

You have to remove first line, not needed in this case, so simply you need to do:-

```
print_r(unserialize($p_ext_items)); // it will give array so use print_r
```

Note:- Working example for you:- https://eval.in/611959

Comment: Thanks for that solutions.